# Accessing string array values in a v-for loop in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to get string values out of an array in a function. My declared component in my template is as follows:

```
<video-preview v-for="video in playlist" vid-id="how-do-I-get-the-string
  -value-from-the-playlist-for-this-iteration"></video-preview>
```

Here is where `playlist` is declared in my `data() { return {} }` in my .vue file:

```
playlist: [
  'videoID1',
  'videoID2',
],
```

And here is my function in the `methods` section of the same .vue file:

```
playImageModal(video) {
  Analytics('content_viewed', vidId)
  // other functionality to play the video
}
```

I need to pass the current value of the `playlist` array into the `Analytics()` function in `playImageModal()`, however, I'm not quite sure how to access that value. I've looked at Vue.js documentation, and it is easy enough to do when my `playlist` array holds generic objects verses holding strings... I simply would do `video.nameOfObjectAttribute` when setting my `vid-id` value in my template. But how do I access these values when there is an array of strings?

Comment: `vid-id="video"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're just missing the `:`

`<video-preview v-for="video in playlist" :vid-id="video"></video-preview>`

it's also a good idea to include a key

`<video-preview v-for="video in playlist" :vid-id="video" :key="video"></video-preview>`

if you want to run a function you **could** (not should)

`<video-preview v-for="(video, i) in playlist" :vid-id="playImageModal(video)" :key="i"></video-preview>`

Usually you would run a function on some event catalyst (like `@click=playImageModal(video)`, but that depends on what playImageModal does

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is correct, but I wanted to add a little more context in case you or other see this that are new [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) and all of its glory!

The key thing you are missing is the [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) directive (shorthand is `:`). This "binds" the value you pass to the prop, which this value could be a variable, a string, a javascript expression, etc. Otherwise, not using bind treats the value passed as a string.

#### Longhand vs shorthand

longhand

```html
<video-preview
   v-for="video in playlist"
   v-bind:vid-id="video"
   v-bind:key="video"
/> <!-- use self-closing tags if no children -->
```

shorthand

```html
<video-preview
   v-for="video in playlist"
   :vid-id="video"
   :key="video"
/>
```

same effect! This is used to bind props to custom components or bind variables to native html element attributes.

#### Binding gotchas

Since the value is treated as a string when not using `v-bind` (aka `:`), there are some common gotchas to look out for when considering whether to bind or not to bind...

```js
// example data
data() {
  return {
    name: 'bob',
  };
}
```

```html
<my-component
  prop1="name"
  prop2="false"
  prop3="true"
  prop4="1 + 1"

  :prop5="name"
  :prop6="false"
  :prop7="true"
  :prop8="1 + 1"
  :prop9="'some random string'"
/>
```

```js
// not binding
prop1 === 'name'
prop2 === 'false' && prop2 !== false
prop3 === 'true' && prop3 !== true
prop4 === '1 + 1'

// binding
prop5 === 'bob'
prop6 === false
prop7 === true
prop8 === 2
prop9 === 'some random string'
```

#### `v-for` object destructuring | es6

The nice thing about v-for with es6 is that you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the iterable "item" if they are objects and "bind" any of the destructured properties to any component prop or element attribute.

```js
data() {
  return {
    // example playlist array
    playlist: [
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'movie1',
      },
      {
        id: 124,
        name: 'movie2',
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

```html
<video-preview
   v-for="{ id, name } in playlist"
   :key="id"
   :vid-id="id"
   :vid-name="name"
   @click="playImageModal(id)"
/>
```

> Note: "Components with no content should be self-closing in single-file components, string templates, and JSX - but never in DOM templates." - [Vue style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended)